# Trying to get equal angles for Semicircle

Tags: c#, wpf, coordinates, trigonometry, angle

I need n shapes (in my code it's "votingParticipants") spread equally on the perimeter of a semi circle (shaped as an arch). Where n can change.

The following code works satisfactorily for 13 shapes/points. It appears as if they have equal angles, but when I change it to 12, the shapes are no longer distributed equally along the  perimeter of the semi circle. I haven't tried other amounts yet, but it need's to work for any number of shapes.

Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong?

(also, if you are up for the challenge: I would really like to have 1 shape always at the top of the circle and it is okay for one side to be one shape more than the other)

here's my code:
Note: the line shape is just for visual to show what the angles are doing

```
// test method with shapes
private void SetupShapes()
{         
var voteResultsParentVisual = VoteResultsCanvas.GetVisualParent<RadSplitContainer>();

var votingParticipants = 13;

var controlWidth = (voteResultsParentVisual.ActualWidth * .80) / votingParticipants;
var controlHeight = controlWidth * 1.2;

var radius = Math.Min(voteResultsParentVisual.ActualHeight, voteResultsParentVisual.ActualWidth/2); 
var angle = (double)votingParticipants * (Math.PI / -180.0f);

var center = new Point
{
    X = voteResultsParentVisual.ActualWidth / 2,
    Y = voteResultsParentVisual.ActualHeight / 2
};

for (var i = 1; i < votingParticipants+1; i++)
{
    var rec = new Rectangle { Width = controlWidth, Height = controlHeight, Fill = Brushes.Red };

    var x = (center.X + Math.Cos(angle * i)*radius) - (double)controlWidth / 2;
    var y = (center.Y + Math.Sin(angle * i) * radius) - (double)controlHeight / 2;

    var line = new Line
    {
        Stroke = Brushes.LightSeaGreen,
        X1 = center.X,
        Y1 = center.Y,
        X2 = x,
        Y2 = y,
        StrokeThickness = 1
    };

    Canvas.SetLeft(rec, x);
    Canvas.SetTop(rec, y);

    VoteResultsCanvas.Children.Add(rec);
    VoteResultsCanvas.Children.Add(line);
}
}
```

Comment: Maybe it would be good to have a screenshot of what it looks like now. And what you do not like about it, or an example how you want it to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your calculation of the angle is wrong.
Correct is

```
var angle = -Math.PI / (votingParticipants - 1);
```

This will use exactly a half circle. And if you change your for-loop to:

```
for (var i = 0; i < votingParticipants; i++)
```

This half-circle will be on a straight line.

Otherwise, if you want to have the same result as with your formula. Just change the angle calculation to this:

```
var angle = -Math.PI / (votingParticipants + 1)
```

And let the for-loop untouched